Efficiently Tracking Order Queue Position In a Limit Order Book Implementation
There are a lot of posts on different ways to implement limit order books, though I never see any discussion on tracking a specific orders queue position efficiently. If I want to ask questions like:

What position is order x at in queue y?
How much volume is in front of and behind order x in queue y?

The only way I can think of doing this is to update each order in the queue with tracking values every time a add/modify/cancel occurs. But this would involve iterating the whole queue each time. Is there a better way?

This is a classic prefix sum problem. You can:

Store the order sizes. Get the position in O(n) and update in O(1).
Store the prefix sums. Get the position in O(1) and update in O(n).
Use a Fenwick tree. Do both in O(log n).

Often, the practical considerations favor approach (2). Why?

Usually getting the position is more urgent to the application logic than making the update. You can defer update to after you compute signals, make strategy decision, or send order messages.
Orders usually get pulled from towards the back of the queue and cancels usually dominate executions, so the average update is much cheaper than the worst case.
The queue is usually short enough that there are not many orders to walk.


Ah, thanks. Ironically, I'm in the middle of testing my implementation on Databento ITCH data! :)

No problem. Glad to hear that. :)
